# Definition of Riemannian manifold

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

I'm posting a series of four questions. Each begins with some sentences that introduce the questions that follow. One major theme that pervades GR that eludes non-physicists is the local connectivity of space-time. Therefore that idea comes up a few times in my series of questions.

1. Riemannian Manifolds are defined by polynomials, differential equations, set notation (trivially as in a circle or sphere), and unions of open balls and open sets. They are characterized by resembling Euclidean space within a neighborhood of a point.

1.1 What are two examples of Riemannian manifolds associated with specific differential equations and alternatively defined using set notation? What are two examples defined by polynomials (other than a sphere or torus)?

1.2 Both embeddings and map projections to 3D (atlases and charts) can be done at the point level. Why are the two mapping functions then different at this level, other than the fact that a chart might include an additional curve and vector fields?

1.3 In the equation for length of a curve:

[image: length of parameterized curve]

the expression within the radicand for ds is fundamentally different from that in the Euclidean plane. The latter is based on the pythagorean formula, whereas the former evaluates differently. Do embedding mappings shed light on this? Are there physical models of such embeddings viewable by the public (e.g. at science museums)?

Comment: Just a note about 1.3: the arc length formula isn’t “fundamentally” different from the Euclidean plane. If you need to evaluate the length of a complicated non-linear arc in flat space, you still use the equation you write (simply with a flat metric instead of a non-flat one).

Comment: Makes sense. Derived the same as the Gaussian version with respect to invariants and the first fundamental  form. But the arc length geometrically, and algebraically after the equation is evaluated, not the general formula, would be different as the pythagorean approximation is not valid.

Comment: I made a second question but was not allowed to post it because it hadn't been 40 minutes. Now I can't find it.

Comment: A Riemann manifold is a topological manifold with a metric. Manifolds are locally Euclidean but with additional structure. It's a complete manifold in the sense for any two points there's a geodesic.  Differential Geometry is the interplay between the local structure and the additional global structure. Euclidean space is a Riemann manifold. In fact, Riemann developed his theory of surfaces on embedded surfaces in $R^3$.

Comment: Thanks for the terminilogy clarification regarding fields of math.

Comment: I did some more reading and read that a riemannian manifold resembles euclidean space within a neighborhood of a point to a first order of approximation, and that neighborhoods can be considered open balls.. I found multiple techniques used to approximate the next value for a function, including a Taylor series. I'm going to do more research on orders of approximation, as applied to 3D Euclidean space first. And I'll try to find example solutions of the arc length equation above and investigate what order of approximation the equation uses.

Comment: one needs differential geometry (unfortunately based on multiple levels of math) to understand how a essentially flat line element ds, ends up being a curved path, when integrated. Orbits are easier to grasp - one can say no force is acting; the path is the most direct. Mathematically it is harder to understand what about a Riemannian manifold constrains a path to be a  geodesic.There are a lot of intervening derivations of tangent vectors, the metric, curvature tensor, etc. Nothing physical constrains it, but I won't find concrete examples of a geodesic on a strictly spatial 4D manifold.

Comment: 4D riemannian manifolds just are curved, the way the surface of a sphere is. It is the object of study - it is the space, whether the manifold is defined using a differential equation, polynomial, or union of sets. The relationship between a local chart and an embedding in R3 - the mathematical details of the mappings, the connection to the order of approximation of line element ds- require rigorous or formal education, well before the formalism of Cartan/Kozul. My best resource (with a patient docent to explain) is to find physical examples of charts and atlases, at a museum/university.